# Can i use VSS 2005 internet client plugin from Visual Studio 2008 to access SVN?

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I use visual studio 2008 for my development purpose. I also have Visual Source Safe 2005 client installed both at my office computer and my laptop. I like the private source control repository provided by xp-dev.com. But it supports SVN.

Is there any way that I can use VSS 2005 internet plug in to access (Check In/Check Out) from SVN repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? Either use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), or one of the plugins that integrate with Visual Studio like [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) or [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

Comment: Are VisualSVN and AnkSVN free?

Comment: VisualSVN is paid, AnkSVN is free and so is Tortoise. Personally I just use Tortoise as I am not bothered about Visual Studio integration.